# thymeleaf html tag with img file extension wild card

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf html tag that displays an image but the image could be a jpg or it could be a png.

Example

```
<img th:src="'http://localhost:8081/'+@{'/images/'}+${image}+'.jpg'"/>
```

I need to substitute the '.jpg' for a wild card extension so as to display either jpg or png

does anyone know what that piece of code at the end is?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something like `http://localhost:8081/images/my_image.*`? What would happen if that matched two or more resources? If you can't write a valid plain URL, without using Thymeleaf, then Thymeleaf cannot generate that (valid) URL.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible. Thymeleaf has no way to detect what is the type of the file and the browser need the full path of the file to show it.

I would advice to detect/add the file extension at the same place your set the ${image} value.

For example by converting the "image" variable to an object with "name" and "extension" fields

```
<img th:src="'http://localhost:8081/'+@{'/images/'}+${image.name}+${image.extension}"/>
```